# Curious to know why my Createjs with Mousetrap is going slow. (jsfiddle provided)

Tags: canvas, dom-events, createjs, easeljs, mousetrap

I'm working with the new createjs, and they've removed flip and addflipframes. Apparently scaleX=-1 is suppose to be faster but now I get a weird lag when I want to move my character left and right. I'm just hoping that I've coded my movement functions faulty, or if its just mousetrap.js not being friendly with create.js

http://jsfiddle.net/w5uZF/8/ This is the jsFiddle with the test game. I'm just learning on how to use the new system.

These are my mousetrap bindings:

```
Mousetrap.bind('a', function(){moveLeft();}, 'keydown');
Mousetrap.bind('d', function(){moveRight();}, 'keydown');
```

these are my functions for movement:

```
function moveRight(){
    var speed = 20;
    sayaka.x += speed;
    sayaka.scaleX= 1;
}

function moveLeft(){
    var speed = 20;
    sayaka.x -= speed;
    sayaka.scaleX= -1;
}
```

I guess it would be good if I showed  how I made my sprite, which has 8 frames to it.

```
var dataSayaka = {
    images: ["http://i.imgur.com/rxDkp2Q.png"],
    frames: {width:133, height:139, regX: 50, regY:50},
    animations: {runRight:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7, "runRight"]}
};

var spriteSheetSayaka = new createjs.SpriteSheet(dataSayaka);
var animationSayaka   = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheetSayaka, "runRight");
sayaka = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheetSayaka, animationSayaka);
```

I'm open to any suggestions and criticism as I would love to know how to increase the movement performance.

I have tried to use native Javascript key events to move my character, however the effect was the same. It's weird how the character lags when I move left and right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the delay between `scaleX=-1/1` and the x-movement:
This has nothing to do with CreateJS(or any other JS framework) this is the way of browsers dispatching keydown events.

Try for example pressing a key in a text-input, you will notice that at first the character you pressed will appear immediatly, but only after a delay of a couple milliseconds the pressed key will cause additional characters to appear. This is to prevent the system from accidentally typing a character multiple times when the used only intended to type just one character.

---

**Solution:** To solve this, just set a flag whenever a certain key is `keydown` and unset the flag on `keyup`. For example you can use a global object `pressedKeys` and whenever `a` is pressed you set `pressedKeys.a = true;` and `onkeyUp -> pressedKeys.a = false;` then in your `handleTick` you check if `a` or `d` is set to `true` and call the according method `moveRight/moveLeft` if so.

Comment: When I was working with quintus, I remember that I had to do that but never understood why, this makes a ton of sense, thanks!!